# HIVE Case Statement: Selecting from another table

Tags: select, hive, case

I am confused on how to get this to work.  I have tried a few different ways to get this to work and I am trying to find the best solution.  I have about 10 case statements that need to reference another table for verification.  So instead of typing out each exclusion and inclusion I created a table.  This works with SAS and works with SQL, though HIVE is the troublemaker.

The CPX.CHP and ONC.ODCD have a list of codes/numbers/etc.

```
When ((main.refrl_req_by_desc in ('MM', 'HP') AND (main.refrl_req_rsn_desc in ('CCM'))) AND (main.PRIMP = CPX.CHP) AND (main.PRIMD != ONC.ODCD)) then 2
```

Appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: how about join these 2 tables and use them in case when - `select case When (
main.refrl_req_by_desc in ('MM', 'HP') 
AND main.refrl_req_rsn_desc in ('CCM') 
AND main.PRIMP = CPX.CHP 
AND main.PRIMD != ONC.ODCD
) then 2
else null 
end
from ONC
join main on id = id`. if its an issue - let us know?

Comment: Thank you, I am joining however it seems like the case statement is still not picking it up right.  A visual examination of the data is showing this case should flag 2 however it is not.

Comment: it shouldn't be. Add one statement at a time and see where its breaking. Sometime data  can have space instead of null or sometime data can have spaces in the beginning or end, they can be uppercase/lowercase. so check these factors out before assuming code is incorrect.

Comment: I just figured this out.  It should be the following:

When ((main.refrl_req_by_desc in ('MM', 'HP') AND (main.refrl_req_rsn_desc in ('CCM'))) AND (main.PRIMP = CPX.CHP) AND (ONC.ODCD IS NULL)) then 2

Comment: completely different statement... glad it worked for you